# Syntax highlighter not working

Tags: javascript, html, css, syntaxhighlighter

I am just following the instruction over [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html) and its not working any help?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/src/shCore.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>

<link href="sh/styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<!--<link href="sh/styles/shCoreDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />-->
<link href="sh/styles/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<pre class="brush: js">
    /**
     * SyntaxHighlighter
     */
    function foo()
    {
        if (counter <= 10)
            return;
        // it works!
    }
</pre>
<script type="text/javascript">
     SyntaxHighlighter.all()
</script>
```

Found some error in console don't know wt to do with it.

Uncaught ReferenceError: XRegExp is not defined shCore.js:123
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Highlighter' of undefined shBrushJScript.js:45
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'all' of undefined test.php:21
Attr.specified is deprecated. Its value is always true.

Comment: Have you tried the web developer toolbar? Any errors in the JavaScript console here?

Comment: Updated question with errors

Comment: @SkyKumar You're acessing the first file using `sh/src/shCore.js` and the scond using `sh/scripts/shBrushJScript.js`, I think they should be in the same directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this **[LINK](http://blog.blakesimpson.co.uk/read/5-installing-syntaxhighlighter-error-xregexp-not-defined)**

Try to keep all your local files for syntax highliter in same directory like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/src/shCore.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/src/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
```

**OR**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/scripts/shCore.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="sh/scripts/shBrushJScript.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I quickly made a simple html site to check your problem and it works for me:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shThemeDefault.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shCore.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/scripts/shBrushJScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="http://alexgorbatchev.com/pub/sh/current/styles/shCore.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
    <pre class="brush: js">
    /**
    * SyntaxHighlighter
    */
    function foo()
    {
        if (counter <= 10)
            return;
        // it works!
    }
    </pre>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        SyntaxHighlighter.all()
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So I'm pretty sure, you're having some referencing issue as the files in the `<script>` tag are not correctly referencing the local files. Try again with the remote files offered by the author of the script. Does it work then?